# Stop loss iterate python pandas numpy

Tags: python, loops, numpy, pandas

I have a trading system with several buy and sell signals.  The system is always either long or short.  Several signals in the same direction can happen but only the first instance in a given direction (long or short) is valid (once long another long signal isn't taken because the system already owns the stock).

I am using Python and Pandas to solve this.  I line up my buys and sells in a column in a dataframe by date:

```
df['BuysandSells'] = [+1,+1,-1,+1,etc]
```

I then create a second column based on the first using ffill.

```
df['Column2'] = df['BuysandSells'].ffill()
```

I then create a third column by shifting Column2:

```
df['Column3'] = df['Column2'].shift()
```

Finally I compare Column2 to Column3 using np.where to find new instances of the buy and sell signals:

```
df['ValidNewSignal'] = np.where(df['Column2']<>df['Column3'],df['Column2'],np.nan)
```

This is effective in creating a list of the accurate buys and sells omitting the redundancies.  I then index into the valid signals.  This all works fine.

However, now I want to determine if a stop loss improves my results.  My goal is to exit if my position gets 'stopped out' (aka current price goes above/below my preset stop loss value).  In order to determine my stoploss I multiply my entry point by a fixed amount (ex $100 entry * 80% = 80.  I then fill this amount down the column using .ffill().  Here inlies the problem.  As with above if I am not stopped out the secondary signals in the same direction are invalid.  However, if I do get stopped out subsequent signals (in the same direction but before a signal in the other direction) become valid.  But the way I have this written it creates a paradox of sorts.

I believe the problem is I need to iterate over rows and create a new column which looks back to the prior row(s).  I have looked for some documentation online and have seen iterows and have explored list comprehensions but neither is supported in depth/seems to solve the problem.  I'm open to using a loop or another approach.

MORE INFO:
A csv file would look like this:

```
Row, Date,BuysandSells,Close
1, 8/19/15,+1,100
2, 8/20/15,+1,101
3, 8/21/15,+1,100
4, 8/24/15,-1,99
5, 8/25/15,NaN,99
6, 8/26/15,-1,98
7, 8/27/15,+1,100
```

I would read it in to a dataframe using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\filename.csv')
```

First I would want to identify the unique records as per my comments above (i.e. eliminate redundancies--see code above).

From there my goal would be to set a stop loss on every new entry.  So say my rule was the stop was 10% of the entry then the code would read:

```
stoplevel = 90%
df['Stop'] = np.where(df['ValidNewSignal'] == 1,df['Close']*stoplevel,np.nan)
```

This is where things get a bit confusing.  I was filling this down using ffill:

```
df['trailingstop'] = df['stop'].ffill()
df['stoppedout'] = np.where(df['Close']<=df['trailingstop'],-1,np.nan)
```

Looking back at the data files above, the system would get long (i.e. buy the stock) in row 1 at 100.  The stop would become 90.  In this instance subsequent buys in rows 2 and 3 are ignored because the stop wasn't hit.  But if, for example, the Close in row 2 was 75 this would mean the system got stopped out and the buy in row 3 would become valid causing a new stoploss to be set.

The big issue is I can't figure out how to determine whether to take the subsequent signals or not because I don't know if I got stopped out.  And depending on my stop level (90%, 95%, etc), I may or may not get stopped out so subsequent signals (and associated new stop losses) would depend on that.  Hence thinking iteration is necessary.  I've tried a lot of shifts and such but can't get anything to work.

Ideal output would show all buys and sells conditioned on what the stop loss level was.

Adding clarity:

There are two main issues:

1. How to dynamically reset the stop loss amount only after a position has been stopped out.
2. How to deal with a day with both a signal and a stop on the same day

Take the following csv:

```
Row,Date,BuysandSells,Close,New Long (if yes 1 else 0),Stop(90%ofnewlong),trailingstop
1,8/19/15,+1,100,1,90,90
2,8/19/15,+1,101,0,NaN,90
3,8/19/15,+1,102,0,NaN,90
4,8/19/15,+1,101,0,NaN,90
5,8/19/15,+1,102,0,NaN,90
6,8/19/15,+1,101,0,NaN,90
7,8/19/15,+1,102,0,NaN,90
8,8/19/15,+1,101,0,NaN,90
9,8/19/15,+1,100,0,NaN,90
10,8/19/15,+1,101,0,NaN,90
11,8/19/15,+1,100,0,NaN,90
12,8/19/15,+1,101,0,NaN,90
13,8/19/15,+1,100,0,NaN,90
```

Here we see that we get a new buy in row 1 and we enter at 100 with a 90 stop.  Each subsequent day we also get a buy signal (buysandsells column) but since we are already long we ignore these.  We also see that the new stop level is ignored (no new entry) and the original stop trails behind (using ffill()).  This is to illustrate a baseline.

Next let's assume a stopout with a slightly different csv:

```
Row,Date,BuysandSells,Close,New Long (if yes 1 else 0),Stop(90%ofnewlong),trailingstop,stopped (1=yes)
1,8/1/15,+1,100,1,90,90,NaN
2,8/2/15,+1,95,0,NaN,90,NaN
3,8/3/15,+1,91,0,NaN,90,NaN
4,8/4/15,0,89,0,NaN,90,1
5,8/5/15,0,90,0,NaN,NaN,NaN
6,8/8/15,+1,90,1,81,81,NaN
7,8/9/15,+1,102,0,NaN,81,NaN
8,8/10/15,+1,101,0,NaN,81,NaN
9,8/11/15,+1,100,0,NaN,81,NaN
10,8/12/15,+1,101,0,NaN,81,NaN
11,8/15/15,+1,100,0,NaN,81,NaN
12,8/16/15,+1,101,0,NaN,81,NaN
13,8/17/15,+1,100,0,NaN,81,NaN
```

On day 1 we get long at 100 as above with a stop of 90.  On day 4 we see the price drops below the original stop level of 90 thus we get stopped out.  The corresponding trailing stop ceases to exist in the next row (not sure how to do this in pandas).  Then in row 6 on 8/8/15 we get another buy signal which we take since there is now no position.  This time the price is 90 so the stop is 81.  Here we ignore subsequent buy signals until we get stopped out again (which doesn't happen).  The inherent problem here is the stops need to be determined essentially line by line and subsequent buys are taken only when the previous position was stopped out.  Pandas abilities (as best I can tell) don't allow for this.  If I ffill() the first instance then when I get down to a stop/new position the stop will remain the original value.  If I reset the stop every new signal and use ffill() I am not actually trailing the correct stop.

The next issue (as a commenter mentioned) is what happens when you get a stop and a signal on the same day.  Logically this sounds simple (if no position take the signal, if a position take the stop) but the way I know how to use Pandas this doesn't work and I can't figure out how to ignore stops after the initial stop (they often come in bunches like the buy and sell signals).  Given all of this, it seems some iterative approach is necessary?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more of an example of how you want the valid buys and sells to relate to the price and stop loss columns?  Maybe show us a few sample inputs and how you'd like the output to look.

Comment: Also, you can probably do the first part of your code more simply, without the intermediate columns: `df['ValidNewSignal'] = np.where(df['BuysandSells'] != df['BuysandSells'].shift(), df['BuysandSells'],  np.nan)`.

Comment: Additional details above please let me know if more is necessary.

Comment: pandas dataframe is mostly for immutable data (i.e. you have data from a CSV or database and you want to analyze it, graph it, do math over entire columns, etc.)  and so may be the wrong data structure for simulating the strategies.  Pandas is fine for holding the price data and reading it from the CSV.  Pandas might also be fine after the simulated trades have been determined.  During the simulating, not so much.

Comment: I understand it a bit more now.  But the exact output you want is still unclear.  For a given stop-loss level (say 90%), can you show us what you'd like the output to be based on the sample input you've already given?

Comment: You don't get stopped at based on the closing price, you get stopped when it's first hit.  In addition to close, you'll need High and Low. An additional complication arises when the signal is reversed on a day that is stopped out.

Comment: @ASGM More details above.

Comment: @Alexander I am assuming a stop based on closing price so High and Low aren't necessary.  Have you figured a way around this same day stop and reversal?  I have tried nested np.where statements but they don't work.  Thanks

Comment: @Paul any suggestions on alternatives?  Thanks

Comment: Assuming a stop based on close is not realistic.  Good luck.